# Outputting (puts, print) in Rails Unit Tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

How come commands like puts and print don't show up in the console when running ActiveSupport::TestCase tests?

Makes it very hard to debug if I can't outputs some inspections in a couple of methods.

Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the rails logger to see your output:

```
Rails::logger.debug "Interesting stuff"
```

Run `tail -f log/test.log` on the command line (from the project's root in a separate Terminal tab or window) to see the results.

Comment: In rails 3 you can see puts output if you run your tests with rake -- trace

Comment: Hmm.. neither of these works with Rails 3, regular ruby test or with spork.

Comment: I don't think you need to actually prefix with the Rails::logger, logger.debug seems to work just fine. Im on rails 3

Comment: This is not working for me in Rails 5. Has logging been changed?

Answer (score 11):

I've just been struggling with this under rails (3.2). I don't know how things have changed between versions but the answers don't actually answer the question. Rather using

```
$stdout.puts msg
```

outputs to the console along with the other console messages when running individual tests.

Comment: simpler answer. Works on **Rails 4.0.13**

Answer (score 3):

I use puts all the time in tests when I'm quickly hacking debugging a single test.  So I don't use rake test:*, rather run the individual test and the output shows up.

```
ruby -Itest test/unit/user/context_test.rb
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use puts in an individual test as follows eg:

```
puts "\n\n #{@object.name}"
```

This will look something like as follows in your terminal window as the tests run

> Started E...EEE
>
> United Kingdom .E
>
> Finished in 2.787886 seconds.

(where `@object.name == "United Kingdom"` in this case)

It's quite a crude method but very quick for simple debugging